# Looping an A to B animation in Swift

Tags: swift, loops, sprite-kit

I'm a swift newbie trying to loop an A to B positional animation. I'm not sure how to reset the position so the animation can loop. Any help appreciated.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let Cloud1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Cloud_01.png")
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        view.scene!.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5,y: 0.5)

        Cloud1.position = CGPoint(x: -800,y: 0)
        Cloud1.xScale = 0.5
        Cloud1.yScale = 0.5

        self.addChild(Cloud1)

        //DEFINING SPRITE ACTION & REPEAT

        let animateCloud1 = SKAction.moveToX(800, duration: 1.4);
        let repeatCloud1 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animateCloud1)

        let group = SKAction.group([ animateCloud1,repeatCloud1]);

        //RUNNING ACTION

        self.Cloud1.runAction(group);

    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        if(Cloud1.position.x == 800){
            Cloud1.position.x = -800

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the Sprite to move back and forth between its current location and the new location you specified.

If so, a way to do this would be to create two animations and put them in a sequence. Then repeat the sequence forever.

```
let animateCloud = SKAction.moveToX(800, duration: 1.4)
let animateCloudBackwards = SKAction.moveToX(Cloud1.position.x, duration: 0)
// Sequences run each action one after another, whereas groups run
// each action in parallel
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([animateCloud, animateCloudBackwards])
let repeatedSequence = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence)

Cloud1.runAction(repeatedSequence)
```

Comment: Thanks, but to clarify, I don't want it to reverse. Just A to B, A to B, A to B etc. So at the end of the animation, it needs to reset at point A and begin again. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Okay, so what if you used the animation to move back but made the duration 0?